# C# Login to a website

Tags: c#, authentication, web, automation, webclient

I'm working on a project where I need to login to an intranet website and fetch some data. There are several examples around about how to login to a website through a program, however I'm unable to use those examples as the website pops up a (Windows Security) login dialog box as following:

[image]

I tried Selenium IDE in Firefox and tried to export the test case in C#, it doesn't record the login action for the site.

Can anyone help me with this?

Solution:

Following is the code I've arrived at after getting help.

```
String siteUrl = "http://XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
String downLoadPageUrl = "http://XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/Search.aspx";
String mainPageUrl = @"http://XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/Main.aspx";
String UserName = "aUserName";
String Password = "aPassword";
String Domain = "aDomain";

NetworkCredential myCred = new NetworkCredential(UserName, Password, Domain);

CredentialCache myCache = new CredentialCache();

myCache.Add(new Uri(siteUrl), "NTLM", myCred);

NameValueCollection parameters = new NameValueCollection();
parameters.Add("ExcelExport","true");

WebClient wc = new WebClient();
wc.Credentials = myCache;
Stream sr = wc.OpenRead(siteUrl);
wc.OpenRead(mainPageUrl);
byte[] response = wc.UploadValues(downLoadPageUrl, parameters);
WebHeaderCollection whc = wc.ResponseHeaders;

String excelName = whc["Content-Disposition"];
outputFile = excelName.Split('=')[1];
outputFile = String.Format("{0}\\{1}", Path.GetTempPath(), outputFile);

File.WriteAllBytes(outputFile,response);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the PowerShell WebClient and your current session

```
$webclient = new-object System.Net.WebClient
$credCache = new-object System.Net.CredentialCache
$creds = new-object System.Net.NetworkCredential("username","password")
$credCache.Add("url", "Basic", $creds)
$webclient.Credentials = $credCache
```

and just [call the script](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kebab/archive/2014/04/28/executing-powershell-scripts-from-c.aspx) inside your C# code.

Another way is by using *[autoit](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/)* since it supports:

> Manipulate windows and processes
>
> Interact with all standard windows controls

Comment: I've posted the solution below my question itself.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft is giving Web ui testing support. see if that helps..

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182536(v=vs.90).aspx